# Android emulator for eclipse on Windows Server 2008

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, windows-server-2008

Hello I search an Android Emulator which works with eclipse on a Windows Server 2008.
The Problem for this is that the most Emulators need  or search for a graphic card but unfortunately windows server dont has one. So does anyone knows a solution for my problem to test an Android Project with an emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about the setup of windows server, but do you have access to a CPU with windows server? If so you might want to look into virtualization with HAXM for intel based computers.

This makes the emulator run really well on the CPU http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-microsoft

Also within the android SDK manager you should be able to download and install this

Comment: unfortunately the windows server dont provide the neccessary  system requirements. So I cant use it.